# Bash - Reasons for stderr to fill up?

Tags: bash, stderr

I wrote a script that works as it should, but for some reason the stderr is being filled up with something. What can go in there and how can I prevent it from happening?

Here's my scripts, which gets a directory as its first argument and names of people as the next x arguments.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

authors=$#
args=("$@")

for ((i = 1; i < authors; i++)); do
    echo ${args[${i}]}
    for D in `find $1 -type d`; do
        appearances=`grep -c ${args[${i}]} $D/*.comp`
        if [ "$appearances" -gt 0 ]; then
            filename=`grep -l ${args[${i}]} $D/*.comp | rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev | cut -d '.' -f 1`
            results=`get_test_stats $D | grep -w ${args[${i}]} | cut -d" " -f2-3`
            echo $filename: $results
        fi
    done
done
```

Thank you!

Comment: **What** is `stderr` being filled with? What are the error messages? Also your loop fails to skip the initial directory. And this script runs `find` multiple times. Why bother with `find` here at all does your `grep` not support `-r`?

Comment: @Etan Reisner: I don't know what is stderr is being filled with, how can I check that? The loop does not go through the directory on purpose. I had something different from find, I can change it back

Comment: What makes you think it's being filled up with anything?

Comment: @that other guy: Because the script that checks my script tells me so

Comment: @GalFl you can redirect stderr to stdout by adding 2>&1 to the end of your command line like: `./script.bsh <args> 2>&1`

Comment: You have a checker script which reports that `stderr` is being written to but which doesn't report what the contents of `stderr` are? That's poor behavior.

Comment: @GalFl Where is what? When you execute your script, add `2>&1` to the end before you hit enter. Then it will print stderr to the console (AKA stdout)

Comment: @mstbaum: Thanks, I did this and nothing showed up. Maybe the current thing I'm checking runs fine but the final check they provided us with has something different

Comment: basic shell debugging technique is to take one command at a time, copy paste from your script to the command line and observe the behavior. Keep expanding what is copy/pasted (one "element" at a time) until you see where your problem is coming from. You can also use `set -vx` near the top of your script to turn on trace mode. You will see each line/block before it is executed, then each command with variable values inserted. add `export PS4='${LINENO} >'` to see what line number is being executed. Good luck.

Comment: for example, `cd /path/to/dir/with/data/youwant/to/process ; get_test_stats "value for D" `. does this work? Now add the next "element" of the script, i.e. `get_test_stats "value for D" | grep -w "value for args"; ` what does that do, etc, etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Commands like `find` and `grep` may encounter a variety of conditions that may be unexpected or not reflected in the output written to `stdout`. To inform the user of such a condition, a warning is written to `stderr`, for example:

```
grep: Binary file [...] matches
find: `[...]': Permission denied
```

In an interactive session, messages written to `stderr` are usually displayed in the terminal, even if `stdout` is redirected, e.g:

```
mj@ap:/tmp$ find > results
find: `./cron-apt.Ex7jHf': Permission denied
```

or captured in a variable, e.g:

```
mj@ap:/tmp$ results=$( find )
find: `./cron-apt.Ex7jHf': Permission denied
```

You can redirect `stderr` as well:

```
find >results 2>errorfile  # redirect stderr to errorfile
find >results 2>/dev/null  # discard stderr
find >results 2>&1         # include stderr in results
```

respectively:

```
results=$( find 2>errorfile ) # redirect stderr to errorfile
results=$( find 2>/dev/null ) # discard stderr
results=$( find 2>&1 )        # include stderr in results
```

See manpage `bash(1)` for more information on redirection (search for `REDIRECTION`).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. However, nothing seems to be solving the problem. As I mentioned, my code works just fine, but stderr seems to be filling up with unknown data. I tried to add the 2>&1 as I was advised here but nothing else from the regular output shows up.

Comment: @GalFl: If you run your script as a whole and redirect its stderr to a file (e.g. `errorfile`) and that file is empty after termination (check with `wc -c errorfile`, should show `0`) then the problem is most likely not in your script (unless it contains conditionals on how it is called, e.g. if a tty is present). Next thing I would have a look at is your checker script and if there is a third program involved: Maybe it calls your script via shell and that shell executes commands (in its initialization files or prompt command, ...) that create the unnecessary output on `stderr`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the problem was:

In the second for loop I was trying to iterate over directories only. But the for loop iterated over files as well. So the variable `results`, in certain iterations, tried to execute the script `get_test_stats` with a file in `$D` instead of a directory, and therefore failed.

Here's the fixed code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

authors=$#
args=("$@")

for ((i = 1; i < authors; i++)); do
    echo "${args[${i}]}"
    for d in $1/*/*.comp; do
                appearances=`grep -c ${args[${i}]} $d`
                if [ "$appearances" -gt 0 ]; then
                    filename=`grep -l ${args[${i}]} $d | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev | cut -d'.' -f1`
                    results=`get_test_stats $1/$filename | grep -w ${args[${i}]} | cut -d' ' -f2-3`
                    echo $filename: $results
                fi
    done
done
```

So to answer the question: In the assignment we were told that if `stderr` is being filled up, it is probably because there is invalid syntax in bash or there is a standard command with invalid arguments.
So you want to check those carefully.